# Error on exporting design package

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, export, design-manager

I'm Trying to Export Design Package via Design Manager
after "Working on it..." screen i got error which i took the correlation ID and used ULS viewer and i found the following error

```
Design Package Export: an error occurred while exporting design 'AwRostamaniPackage'
at web /. Error: Error generating solution files in temporary directory. Stacktrace:   
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebAsSolution()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSolutionExporter.ExportWebToGallery(SPWeb web, String solutionFileName, String title, String description, ExportMode exportMode, Boolean includeContent, String workflowTemplateName, String destinationListUrl, Action`1 solutionPostProcessor, Boolean activateSolution)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.DesignPackage.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Export>b__b()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.DesignPackage.Export(SPSite site, String packageName, Boolean includeSearchConfiguration)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.DesignPackageExport.<ButtonExport_Click>b__0(SPLongOperation longOperation)
```

Process: w3wp.exe
any idea ?

Comment: This failure might caused by corrupt permissions on the temporary directories.

Did you use the same account to create the design package?
I recommend to restore the directory permission or use another application service account which has been given the access to the temporary directory to see if the error still occurs.